# How to install Web Deploy for IIS, now that Web Platform Installer has been retired?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2022, web-platform-installer, webdeploy

I'm trying to install WebDeploy (for publishing IIS sites from remote Visual Studio) on a new Windows Server 2022 machine.

We used to use the Web Platform Installer to install WebDeploy, however this tool has been retired as of December 31, 2022.

I've found an .msi installer for Web Deploy version 4.0, however when running the installer I am told there is a newer version installed already.  I don't believe this is the case - I can't find any sign of it being installed.

[web deploy installer message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf54u.jpg)

I guess what I am asking is: what is the current preferred way to install Web Deploy?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Web Deploy 4 is installed/managed as part of the Visual Studio 20nn installation since 2017.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same trouble installing this on Windows Server 2022 because there is no WebPlatform Installer anymore. This is how I managed to do it:

- First make sure that you have "Management Service" installed.
- Restart Server to make sure changes are applied
- Then install WebDeploy from the [official website](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy).
- After that just restart the IIS and that should be it.

Adding Roles and Features
[image: Installed Management Service]

Installed WebDeploy UI is visible in IIS
[image: Installed WebDeploy UI]

Comment: Ty gtu.  I had Web Deploy installed prior to seeing this.  After adding the Management Service and rebooting, I still didn't see the deploy option.  Running the webdeploy msi file again gave me a repair option.  Running the repair and restarting the IIS Manager gave me the deploy button.

Comment: Important note: When installing WebDeploy, you must choose Complete installation. Without this, deployment from Visual Studio will not work. https://serverfault.com/questions/613634/could-not-connect-to-remote-computer-web-deploy-error-destination-not-reachable